# How to use a List as a Model Attribute in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, forms, binding

I have my Home controller like this:

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome(@ModelAttribute("myValuesInRows") List<String> myValuesInRows,  ModelMap model) {
        List<Spravochnik> dropDown = spravochnikService.findAll("sprav_of_spravs");
        List<String> justValuesInRows = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Spravochnik sprav : dropDown) {
            for(List<String> vals : sprav.getValuesInRows()) {
                for(String v : vals) {
                    justValuesInRows.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=1; i<justValuesInRows.size(); i+=2) {
            myValuesInRows.add(justValuesInRows.get(i));
        }
        model.addAttribute("myValuesInRows", myValuesInRows);
        return new ModelAndView("home", model);
    }
```

and my Home view has this Select I'm using:

```
<f:form>
<f:select path="myValuesInRows" items="${myValuesInRows}" name="tableName" id="tableName">
</f:select>
</f:form>
```

When I try to show it Spring shows this error:

`No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.List`.

I would like to connect my select to this List I'm passing, how is it done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the classes which implement `List`, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), which have default constructors.

```
@ModelAttribute("myValuesInRows") ArrayList<String> myValuesInRows
```

You can find a list of all known implementing classes of `List` here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: I edited my code and now I have a new error:`Invalid property 'myValuesInRows' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'myValuesInRows' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

Comment: @Nikrango Can you share some github repo or similar that I can test this?

Comment: On the other hand you could try to pass the list inside the `model` and not as a separate parameter.