# Spring + Thymeleaf + JS, how to bind elements?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've problem with binding elements with Java Spring+Thymeleaf. How can I bind the list and the new added elements along with it?

It is supposed to work like this: https://codepen.io/esatest/pen/jOVLarr and I should be able to add new email addresses to the list.

When updating person name it gets updated and everything is fine but I cannot get emailAddresses binded at all. Am I doing something wrong here or how we supposed to handle features like this?

Person object:

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> emailAddresses;
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/person/{id}")
    public String getPersonData(
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final Model model
            @PathVariable String id) {

        List<Person> persons = client.getAll(null);
        
        for(Person person : persons) { 
            if(person.getId() == Long.parseLong(id)) {
                model.addAttribute(MODEL_PERSON, personEdit);
                model.addAttribute(MODEL_RENDER_UTIL, new RenderUtil());
                break;
            }
        }
    return FRAGMENTS_PERSON;
}

@PostMapping("/person/{id}")
public String setPersonData(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final Model model,
        @PathVariable String id,
        @ModelAttribute("person") PersonEdit personForm) {

    List<Person> persons = client.getAll(null);
    
    for(Person person : persons) 
    { 
        if(person.getId() == Long.parseLong(id))
        {
            Person personEdit = personForm.getPerson();

            person.setDisplayName(personEdit.getName());
            person.setEmailAddresses(personEdit.getEmailAddresses());
            client.updateSingle(person, audit);
        }
    }
    
    model.addAttribute(MODEL_PERSONS, persons);
    model.addAttribute(MODEL_RENDER_UTIL, new RenderUtil());

    return FRAGMENTS_PERSONS;
}
```

Result handling:

```
<th:block th:if="${person}">
    <br/>
    <form method="POST" name="form" id="form" th:object="${person}">
        <table class="simple table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td th:text="*{person.getId()}">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" th:field="*{person.name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EmailAddresses:</td>
                <td>
                    <fieldset id="emails" name="emails" th:field="*{person.emailAddresses}" >
                      <div th:each="email: *{person.emailAddresses}">
                        <label th:value="${email}" th:text="${email}"></label>
                        <button type="button" onclick="removeEmail(this)">Remove</button>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                 
                  <br />
                  <input name="email" type="text" />
                  <button type="button" onclick="addAccount()">+ Add account</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        
        </table>
    </form>
</th:block>
```

JS:

```
function removeEmail(button) {
   button
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .removeChild(button.parentElement)
}

function addEmail() {
    var emailToBeAdded = document.form.email.value;

    var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
    label.innerHTML = emailToBeAdded;

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Remove";
    button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
        removeEmail(this)
    });

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(label);
    div.appendChild(button);

    emails.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Your answer should be below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855987/how-to-use-a-list-as-a-model-attribute-in-spring